# Is there a way to use gitlab command line export functionalities on a Windows 10 server?

Tags: git, windows-10, gitlab

I am setting up a gitlab project for my team's workflow, but the catch is that we all use Windows 10. I installed gitlab on my Windows 10 workstation, but could not configure it because the "bash for windows" feature does not include an actual ubantu kernel, and therefore does not have a /com directory, which gitlab configuration needs. I would like to set up a nightly service to run gitlab's export commands on a Windows 10 server. Has anyone figured out how to either run gitlab on Windows 10 or export in another way?

This is the code I was planning to use if gitlab had configured correctly:

```
    sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:create RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Is `/com` a typo? That's not a directory that GitLab uses.

Comment: When I tried running: 

        "gitlab-ctl reconfigure",

I got this error: "STDERR: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused", so it looked to me like the configuration does use the /com directory.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab is not supported on Windows.

If you proceed this will be just the beginning of your struggles.

Instead, simply install a Linux VM and install GitLab there.

Comment: I am trying it out because the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" is technically a Linux subsystem. I'm not exactly running GitLab on Windows per se.